# is it safe to install elementary OS on Acer Swift 3 SF-314-57

Tags: release-juno, acer

I'm new to linux, and I tried booting elementary OS on my Swift 3 (SF314-57) without installing, first thing I noticed is trackpad is not working.
I read on another thread, in BIOS, trackpad should be set to basic, but I don't have that in this OS

I tried ubuntu too, the touchpad works

if I install Elementary OS on it will be able to solve the trackpad problem?

Comment: On Swift 3 SF314-52 works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu. If you had no problems with the hardware on Ubuntu there's a strong indication that you'll be able to use it without any hiccups on Elementary too.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of how Elementary OS is released. Juno currently ships with Ubuntu 18.* LTS as it's base. It might be that the trackpad issue was solved in Ubuntu 20.* which is the latest version.